# r.history returning an empty list [python]

Tags: python, html, python-requests-html

Here is the code in main.py

```py
import requests

URL = 'localhost:80'
if 'http' not in URL: URL = 'http://'+ URL
r = requests.get(URL)
for resp in r.history:
    print(r.url)
```

Here is the code in webserver.py

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<script>location.href = "https://youtube.com"</script>'

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 80)
```

r.history returns an empty list when I run main.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna get the redicrection url:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect('https://python.org')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 80)
```

req.py

```
import requests

URL = 'localhost:80'
r = requests.get("http://localhost:80", allow_redirects=True)
print(r.url)
```

If you wanna get the history of the request

```
import requests

URL = 'localhost:80'
r = requests.get("http://localhost:80", allow_redirects=True)
print(r.history)
```